# Thread.join() doesn't let the thread itself to update the GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I have problem: **i call thread.join()**, i'm sure the thread is corretcly working by a stdout logging, **but it can't update the GUI**.

The example is really simple: **the thread should update a progressbar 5 times**: the progressbar starts full emptied, at time 0, and became fully filled, at time 5. **Every update occurs every second**, so it will take 5 seconds in total.

**After thread.join() another window will be showed**.

*But the problem is that at the moment of thread.join() i can see just the stdout logging, but the progressbar isn't being updated. I have to wait 5 seconds, then i can see a fully filled progressbar and at the end the other window is showed.*

**So i can't see any update to my GUI, to my progressbar, during those 5 seconds**

Here is the code:

```
def Interrupt_Button_clicked(widget, args=()):

    t = threading.Thread(target=pulsing2, args=())
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    builder.get_object('Azioni_Window').show()


def pulsing2():

    progressbar.set_inverted(True)
    fraction = 0.0
    while True:
        fraction += 0.2
        progressbar.set_fraction(fraction)
        print fraction # THIS WORKS CORRECTLY EVERY TIME, 5 TIMES IN TOTAL (1/0.2)
        time.sleep(1)
        if fraction == 1:
            break

progressbar = builder.get_object('Progressbar1')
builder.get_object('Ferma_trovarete_Button').connect('clicked', Interrompi_Button_clicked)
builder.get_object('Trovarete_Window').show()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding 0.2 five times and expecting it to equal 1.0, since 0.2 can't be represented exactly in binary. If it works here, it is a coincidence.

Comment: **print fraction** at time 5 prints 1.0, **Gtk.Progressbar.get_fraction()** returns me 1.0

Comment: As I said, *if it works here, it's a coincidence.* So, it works. It's a coincidence.

Comment: 0.20 would be better than 0.2? What would you do?

Comment: Use integers. For example, count to 5 by 1, divide by 5.0 when passing to the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the GUI from a background thread, which is not supported by GTK. If you need to update the GUI from a background thread, use [`gobject.idle_add`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add) to schedule the widget to be updated in the main thread.

```
def pulsing2(callback=None):

    progressbar.set_inverted(True)
    fraction = 0.0
    while True:
        fraction += 0.2
        gobject.idle_add(progressbar.set_fraction, fraction)
        print fraction # THIS WORKS CORRECTLY EVERY TIME, 5 TIMES IN TOTAL (1/0.2)
        time.sleep(1)
        if fraction == 1:
            break
    gobject.idle_add(builder.get_object('Azioni_Window').show)
```

You also need to remove the call to `t.join()` from `Interrupt_Button_clicked`, because it will block your main thread inside of the function call, which means the gtk event loop won't be able to run and actually update the GUI widget.

That said, I think you could refactor this to not use threads at all, and instead use [`gobject.timeout_add`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) to schedule your update code to run every second:

```
def Interrupt_Button_clicked(widget, args=()):
    def cb():
        builder.get_object('Azioni_Window').show()
        print ("pulsing2 is done")

    pulsing2(callback=cb)

def pulsing2(fraction=0.0, callback=None):  
    progressbar.set_inverted(True)
    fraction += 0.2
    progressbar.set_fraction(fraction)
    print fraction # THIS WORKS CORRECTLY EVERY TIME, 5 TIMES IN TOTAL (1/0.2)
    if fraction != 1:
        gobject.add_timeout(1, pulsing2, fraction, callback)
    else:
        if callback:
            gobject.idle_add(callback)
```

Comment: i think you have misunderstand my question: the main thread does nothing during the child thread function. The child thread works, because it prints the right fraction every sec, but i can't see any update to my progressbar.

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Ah, I think I know what the issue is. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i've also tried gobject.idle_add, maybe yours is better. let's read the code

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Note that You still need to remove the call to `t.join()`, because it will block your main thread inside `Interrupt_Button_Click`, and prevent the gtk event loop from running.

Comment: ok, but the join was useful because the other window should be showed AFTER the child thread. See the edit on your answer. I've added the .show() call after pulsing2().
I could easily get this result just by cutting off the join() in my example

Comment: @Jimmy5nomama just add the call to show the other window to the background thread, and call it using `idle_add`.

Comment: the problem is that if you add a generic print after pulsing2(), then the print doesn't happened after pulsing2() has ended.

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana What do you mean by a "generic print"? And why can't you just do the same thing we did for showing the second window - add the print to `pulsing2` itself?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana You have to adjust your usual program layout a bit when you're dealing with a framework built on an event loop (like `gtk`). If you have an asynchronous function (like `pulsing2`), you have to use a callback-style approach to run code after it's finished, rather than just making the call after `pulsing2` itself is executed. I've edited my second example to show how you can tell `pulsing2` to execute some arbitrary function when it completes.

Comment: This works, but.. think **Interrupt_Button_clicked** as my main function: it calls many methods and every time it has to wait the result. This can't work by this framework. 
I should move on the remaining 200-300 lines of code, located below **pulsing2(callback=cb)**, below **if callback:**. It's a messy and i don't think this would work.
I really need a lock, a while loop, something that BLOCKS my main from going ahead.